# Generating a changelog automatically with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, changelog

In our projects we need to maintain (manually) a changelog file with the details of every change made in any of the files of the project. As anyone can expect, the developers frequently forget to update this file. So my question would be: Is there any way to make TortoiseSVN automatically update this file with every commit message? If not, is there any option in Tortoise to export the contents of the log messages?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a crazy requirement - push back. the log can be generated on demand, even as part of your build, there is no need to write a hook for this.
Install the optional commandline integration with tortoise and then use the [svn log](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) command or the much fancier [svn2cl](http://arthurdejong.org/svn2cl/) script that comes with some xsl files that can style the output.

Answer (score -1):

yes, a server-side post-commit hook can extract the log message and append it (along with files changed and revision number) to a file.

See svnlook, svn info and svn log - all take parameters to get the data for a revision, and the post-commit hook will give you the revision just committed (as the 2nd param, the 1st param it gives you is the path to the repo)

You can do this on the clients in Tortoise using its' [client-side hooks](http://sfalla.wordpress.com/2008/10/06/tortoise-svn-client-side-hook-scripts/) but server=side is better as you guarantee it will work even if the client is not configured or the developer uses an alternative tool, such as AnkhSVN or VisuaSvn.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to SVN and I didn't know you could do that!

Comment: Just be cause you can doesn't mean it's a smart thing to do.